# Spring boot microservice( Api Gatway) on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, deployment, microservices, aws-code-deploy

and trying to deploy micro-services build in spring boot on aws but didn't know which aws service is suitable for perticular spring micro-service(Could Config, Service Discovery, Api Gatway, and vault).

I build an api gateway service on spring boot, but when it comes to deployment on aws i got confused with the aws api gateway.

Do we need both of the to work together? or we can just setup springBoot Api gatway on ec2 instance.

And its out of context but, do we need separate ec2 for small service like 'Service Discovery', 'Config Service' etc.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway is just a kind of routing to your application, no matter if it is hosted on serverless platform or on EC2 container.

You can try to deploy your Spring Boot app on AWS Lambda environment and this way you don't have to think of configuring the server environment. You have to be awarded the cold start of the application in this case. You can google more about it how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway is like facade in front of your microservices for communication with external services. There are several ways to use/implement API gateway depending on requirements such as Request Routing, API composition(calling multiple services and combining responses), Authentication, Caching etc.

AWS API gateway is good if you need request routing feature but it can't perform API composition. In such case you need to implement your own custom API gateway using technologies such as Spring Cloud Gateway & Reactive programming.

GraphQL is another popular technology to implement API Gateway.

P.S. - Service Discovery is another concept. In real life you will use Kubernetes or Service Mesh which will internally do Service Registry and Discovery.